# Javascript how add markers in html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm using the plyr.io with tutor lms plugin.
But I have a problem!

I enabled video markers, but it enabled all videos on the site, I can't choose which video I want.

````
        if ( is_single_course( true ) ) {
            wp_enqueue_style( 'tutor-plyr', tutor()->url . 'assets/packages/plyr/plyr.css', array(), TUTOR_VERSION );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'tutor-plyr', tutor()->url . 'assets/packages/plyr/plyr.polyfilled.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), TUTOR_VERSION, true );
        } ```
````

Comment: use a custom field on the page you do want markers on videos. pass that custom field value to the client to decide whether to add markers or not.

Comment: this is exactly what i was thinking but i can't do it